# Expo Android build freezes on splash screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

im using SDK 48 and tried solve this by downgrading to SDK 47 but does not working

Using expo go and development mode im not have ploblems but when i try compile the app using eas build --profile production --platform android the app compile succefully and when open the app freezes on splash screen

im triying downgrading from SDK 48 to 47 but this does not working

My package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "yoreparto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.14",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "1.3.5",
    "expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^2.3.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "firebase": "^9.22.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.1",
    "expo-firebase-core": "~6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And my App.js file

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
import AppContainer from './pages/MainNavigation';
import { PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: Constants.manifest.extra.apiKey,
  authDomain: Constants.manifest.extra.authDomain,
  projectId: Constants.manifest.extra.projectId,
  storageBucket: Constants.manifest.extra.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: Constants.manifest.extra.messagingSenderId,
  appId: Constants.manifest.extra.appId
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    initLoad()
  }, []);
  

  const initLoad = async () => {
    try {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        Regular: require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"),
        Bold: require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"),
        SemiBold: require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf"),
        Italic: require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf"),
        NunitoBold: require("./assets/fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Bold.ttf"),
        Nunito: require("./assets/fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Regular.ttf"),
      });
      setLoading(true);
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  
  if(!loading) return null;

  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <AppContainer/>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```